# WooCommerce Divi Product Taglist broken

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem with Divi and WooCommerce. The taglist on the article page is broken. The tags are not shown in a row, but in a column. I noticed it just now and I'm sure I didn't change anything.

Ever heard of this issue? I can't find an option to fix it, so I might need to style it myself.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After disabling the WooCommerce Multilingual plugin everything is back to normal.